# How to change the value of just the current select box instead of all with the same name?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel

I created five select boxes with a dependent select box where the value of the second select box would vary on what i select on the first select box.

```
<tr>
<td>
<select name="brand" class="form-control select2" id ="brand">
 <option value="0" selected="true" disabled="true">Select Brand</option>
  @foreach($brands as $key => $m)
   <option value="{!!$key!!}">{!!$m!!}</option>
  @endforeach
</select>
</td>
<td>
 <select name="size" class="form-control" id="size">
 </select>
</td>
<td>
<select name="brand" class="form-control select2" id ="brand">
 <option value="0" selected="true" disabled="true">Select Brand</option>
  @foreach($brands as $key => $m)
   <option value="{!!$key!!}">{!!$m!!}</option>
  @endforeach
</select>
</td>
<td>
 <select name="size" class="form-control" id="size">
 </select>
</td>
<td>
<select name="brand" class="form-control select2" id ="brand">
 <option value="0" selected="true" disabled="true">Select Brand</option>
  @foreach($brands as $key => $m)
   <option value="{!!$key!!}">{!!$m!!}</option>
  @endforeach
</select>
</td>
<td>
 <select name="size" class="form-control" id="size">
 </select>
</td>
<td>
<select name="brand" class="form-control select2" id ="brand">
 <option value="0" selected="true" disabled="true">Select Brand</option>
  @foreach($brands as $key => $m)
   <option value="{!!$key!!}">{!!$m!!}</option>
  @endforeach
</select>
</td>
<td>
 <select name="size" class="form-control" id="size">
 </select>
</td>
<td>
<select name="brand" class="form-control select2" id ="brand">
 <option value="0" selected="true" disabled="true">Select Brand</option>
  @foreach($brands as $key => $m)
   <option value="{!!$key!!}">{!!$m!!}</option>
  @endforeach
</select>
</td>
<td>
 <select name="size" class="form-control" id="size">
 </select>
</td>
</tr>
```

The available sizes for the brand would then be displayed on the 2nd select box.

I have five of these select boxes and i will be inserting it into different rows.
My problem is when i change the value of my first select box, all 5 of the dependent select box which is the second box changes as well. 
I only want the current row to change and not all 5 of them to change.

Here is my js code:

```
$('select[name="brand"]').on('change', function() {
        var brandID = $(this).val();
        if(brandID) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/findSize/ajax/'+brandID,
                type: "GET",
                dataType: "json",
                success:function(data) {
                    $('select[name="size"]').empty();
                    $.each(data, function(key, value) {
                        $('select[name="size"]').append('<option value="'+ key +'">'+ value +'</option>');
                    });
                },
                error:function(){
            }
            });
        }else{
            $('select[name="size"]').empty();
        }
    });
```

Here is the code from my shopcontroller

```
public function brandList()
{
  $brands = DB::table("brands")->lists("name","id");
  return view('shop.brandslist',compact('brands'));
}

public function findSize($id)
{
    $sizes = DB::table("sizes")
                ->where("brand_id",$id)
                ->lists("size","id");
    return json_encode($sizes);
}
```

Comment: What are these 5 dropdowns you speak of? Are they brand or size? How are your brand and size `select`s displayed (connected) on the DOM? *"I have five of these select boxes and i will be inserting it into different rows"*.IS there a table? Please post all the relevant HTML so that we can see how the elements are represented.

Comment: Your main problem here is that you are not establishing a unique relationship between your "brand" select element and the corresponding "size" element, so when you retrieve your data for the sizes and then update DOM with your `$.each()` function you are effectively updating all of the "size" selects. The best way to approach it is use a unique name for each "brand" select and each "size" select and add `data-brand` and `data-sizes` to the corresponding brand and select boxes which then you can use to update only specific selects.

Comment: @adiga sorry for the lacking information its my first time posting a question here. The 5 dropdowns are the brand and the dependent select box which appears after selecting an option from the brand dropdown is the size select box. I edited my html code you can check again. Basically the size select box value changes depending on what the brand is selected. I just want to update the first size select box but all 5 of the size select boxes updates due to the selected brand size because they have the same names. Is there a way to keep the same names or do i just give them unique names instead?

Comment: @jamesyap oh don't apologize. I was simply asking questions one might get when they see your question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `$(this)` instead. In your change handler, `$(this)` will refer to the current `select` element that triggered the function.

Since your `brand` and `size` selects are are in consecutive `td`, we can get the `size` select element using [`.closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/), [`.next()`](https://api.jquery.com/next/), and [`.find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/)

```
$('select[name="brand"]').on('change', function () {
    var brandID = $(this).val();
    // ↓ this gets the size select element for that particular brand
    var $size = $(this).closest("td").next().find('select[name="size"]');

    if (brandID) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/findSize/ajax/' + brandID,
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                $size.empty(); // only empties the size select you want
                $.each(data, function (key, value) {
                    $size.append('<option value="' + key + '">' + value + '</option>');
                });
            },
            error: function () {
            }
        });
    } else {
        $size.empty();
    }
});
```

The key and confusing thing perhaps here is the `selector` for size. So here is how it works. So that, should your requirements change, you can update it on your own.

- `$(this).closest("td")` : Gets the `td` element which has `brand`
  select element you changed.
- `.next()`: Gets the next (sibling) `td` element. (This `td` contains
  the `size` select you want to target)
- `.find('select[name="size"]');`: Finds the `select` element where
  `name` atribute is "size". ([Attribute selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/))

Since you only have one `select` element in each `td`. You can also do like:

```
$(this).closest("td").next().find('select');
```

Comment: It didn't produce any error but the size select box remains empty. I checked the size and it returned a null value.

Comment: I don't know `php` so is your server side code working properly? Do you get `data` in your success callback?

Comment: I was mistaken, it produces the size values when i tried the data success callback. The only issue is it does not append on the size select box.

Comment: @jamesyap I missed `var` before declaring `$size`. Don't think that's the issue. But you can try it. `var $size = $(this).closest("td").find('select[name="size"]');`. Also do a `alert($size.length)` just after that line. See what value gets alerted?

Comment: I also put a console.log on success and it displays all the values however alert($size.length) returned 0.

Comment: @jamesyap damn it, I didn't read the question properly. Even the `size` selects are in a seperate `td`. Try with this (hopefully this is the last time): `var $size = $(this).closest("td").next().find('select[name="size"]');`

Comment: @jamesyap yes of course. Btw, you can further simplify it with this: `var $size = $(this).closest("td").next().find('select');`

Comment: @jamesyap updated the answer with how each selector works. You can go through all 4 jquery links and understand how this works. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to achieve this: in the following implementation a unique `brand` name is used as the ***name***="*brand*" value of a `product` ***`<select>`*** element and when the `value` of this element changes another ***`<select>`*** element for this specific `product` is displayed and populated with ***`<option(s)>`*** for this specific `product`.

**Note:** The JavaScript part of the snippet contains a dummy JSON data object to further simplify understanding of this solution but if your data structure differs then the code needs to be modified accordingly.

---

#### User Story:

- As a user I want to be able to **select** a **product** for a **specific brand**
- As a user I want to see a **size selection box appear** when a product is selected
- As a user I want to see the **size selection options change** when a different product is selected
- As a user I want to be able to **select a size** for the specific product

#### Proposed Solution:

- Make each brand's product selection box identifiable in a unique manner
- When brand's product selection changes to a non-empty value show a size selection box and set a unique name attribute
- Populate the product's size selection with sizes for the selected product
- When brand's product selection changes to an empty value remove all size options, remove the unique name attribute value and hide size selection box

---

Here is a simple functioning code to showcase this functionality:

```js
// demoApp object used for this demo only
demoApp = {};

// demoApp.data dumy data to be used for this demo only
demoApp.data = {
 "adidas": {

  "shoes": {
   "sizes": ["10", "11", "12"]
  },
  "pants": {
   "sizes": ["32", "33", "35"]
  },
  "shirts": {
   "sizes": ["sm", "m", "l", "xl"]
  }

 },
 "nike": {

  "hats": {
   "sizes": ["8", "9", "10", "11", "12"]
  },
  "jackets": {
   "sizes": ["41", "42", "43", "44"]
  },
  "shirts": {
   "sizes": ["sm", "m", "l", "xl"]
  }
 }
}

// when a value of any select element changes
$("select").on("change", function(e) {
 // check if the first value is empty - this narrows our selection down only to product select boxes since size select's options all have values
 if (!$(this).find("option:first-child").val()) {
  // set local brand variable to the value of this select's name attribute - for example 'adidas'
  var brand = $(this).attr('name');
  // set local product type to selected value - for example 'shows'
  var type = $(this).val();
  // if type is not empty we know a product is selected
  if (type) {
   // select correct sizes element using the data-related attribute, set its name attribute to brand_sizes - for example adidas_sizes, remove all options, show element
   $("select[data-related='" + brand + "']").attr('name', brand + '_sizes').html('').show();
   // for each size value for the selected brand and proucts populate options within the size select element
   $.each(demoApp.data[brand][type]["sizes"], function(key, value) {
    $("select[data-related='" + brand + "']").append('<option value="' + value + '">' + value + '</option>');
   });
   // else the first option was selected therefore remove the size select element
  } else {
   $("select[data-related='" + brand + "']").attr('name', '').html('').hide();
  }
 }
});
```

```css
/* set display:none on all select elements that have 'data-related' attribtue set - in this case it's only the size select boxes */

select[data-related] {
  display: none;
 }
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <title>Products and Sizes</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

 <select name="adidas">
  <option value="">Select Adidas Products</option>
  <option value="shoes">Shoes</option>
  <option value="pants">Pants</option>
  <option value="shirts">Shirts</option>
</select>
<select data-related="adidas"></select>

<select name="nike">
  <option value="">Select Nike Products</option>
  <option value="hats">Hats</option>
  <option value="jackets">Jackets</option>
  <option value="shirts">Shirts</option>
</select>

<select data-related="nike"></select>
</body>
</html>
```